# Getting errors connecting to mail servers using SMTP in python

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I want to send a mail using smtplib in python. I tried to connect to the gmail server and protonmail server.But getting these errors,

When trying to connect to Gmail server,

```
import smtplib
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',465)
```

Error: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time"

When trying to connect to protonmail server,

```
import smtplib
Server=smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1',1025)
```

Error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Please let me know how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for email,

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword")
```

Comment: i tried this and I have enabled 2FA as well, but still getting the same error.